# Cannot connect to D Link router - even though the ipad can

Tags: windows-7, networking, router

I was trying to play minecraft with my friends on my server. They could connect to my server just fine, but I couldn't. So I decided to check on the router settings by going to 192.168.1.1 At this point my internet was working fine. However, the page refused to load, and chrome eventually responded with a timeout error. So after checking online I reset my router to its factory settings by holding down the reset button on the router. Lo and behold, I cannot connect to the Internet at all now. My windows 7 PC is trying to connect via Ethernet (I have tried wireless as well) but all I get is "identifying...no network access". A while later I get a small yellow triangle with an exclamation mark. However, my sister's ipad can connect just fine, and can even access 192.168.1.1 (I'm currently posting from her ipad). How can I fix this problem and connect my PC to the Internet again? (I've trying restarting and resetting the router multiple times.)

Comment: Have you tried restarting your PC? What is the output from ipconfig /all? Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have tried restarting my pc, and I can't copy all of ipconfig because my pc can't connect to the Internet. Is there a specific part of ipconfig that would be useful?

Comment: @DavidPostill IPv4 is 192.168.1.5, gateway is 192.168.1.1

Comment: @DavidPostill I've tried network diagnostics, it hasn't helped

Comment: Last idea is to delete the network connection and create a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill delete? How?

Comment: Ensure that you have the relevant drivers pre-downloaded
- Start > run > devmgmt.msc > expand Network Adapters > right-click on each adapter and select 'Uninstall'
- Reboot
- Re-install drivers

Comment: That will also delete all existing network connections

Comment: @DavidPostill no effect :/

Comment: See also [Fix Unidentified Network and No Network Access in Windows 7](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/fix-unidentified-network-and-no-network-access-in-windows-7/) for other things to try

Comment: You might try a winsock reset. In a cmd prompt run >netsh winsock reset and then reboot to basically reset your TCP/IP stack.